# The gap between two equivalent optimization problems

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

If $A \text{ and } B $ are two equivalent optimization problem. The $\epsilon-$optimal value, $A_\epsilon^*$, of $A$ was obtained, can we claim that $| B^* - A_\epsilon^* | = |A^* - A_\epsilon^*|$, or more generally $dist(B^* , A_\epsilon^*) = dist(A^* , A_\epsilon^*)$ where $B^*$ is the optimal value of problem $B$ and $A^* = B^*$ (since they are equivalent) is the optimal value of problem $A$, and $dist$ is any distance measure?

To narrow the question, we may assume that both optimization problems are convex.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *equivalent* problems ?

Comment: When we write $A^* = B^*$ we generally expect that $f(A^*)$ = $f(B^*)$ for any function $f$ (notably the distance to anything else), but i'm not completely sure what the equality means in your setup...

Comment: @HugoManet. Quoting from Boyd's book: "We call two problems equivalent if from a solution of one, a solution of the other is readily found, and vice versa." i.e., they have the same optimal value and correspondence of optimal solutions

Comment: The sentence before that is "In this book we will use the notion of equivalence of optimization problems in an informal way", which is important. And then, in the chapter they allow simple invertible transformations of the variables, the constraint of the problem, the objective function... Which means you don't always have $A^* = B^*$, because the problem of minimizing $f(x)$ and minimizing $f(x) + 1$ are *equivalent* but don't have the same value. Yet, if you give me the value of one problem, I can give you the value of the other one without computing too much (which is what *equivalence* is)

Comment: @HugoManet I see, thanks. Would the answer on my question be yes if I am talking about optimal *solution*?

Comment: Your question says "$A^* = B^*$" which is not always true, so comparing $B^*$ with $A_\epsilon^*$ generally makes no sense. To try and correct this, I would interpret the question as something like "*Can we claim that $|\varphi(A^*) - \varphi(A_\epsilon^*)| = |A^* - A_\epsilon^*|$, where $\varphi$ is a way to transform a solution of problem $A$ to problem $B$ ?*".

Comment: And there, the answer is *no*, because the transformations allowed with equivalent problems don't necessarily respect this. For example, minimizing $f(x)$ and minimizing $5f(x)+2$ are *equivalent*, but the differences are 5 times higher in the second problem than in the first one.

Comment: @HugoManet I concur with your interpretation of my question. I will edit the question.